# Why isn't iPhone minicom reading serial data from Arduino?

Tags: arduino, serial, iphone

Alright, this is my first time posting on electronics.stackexchange.com but I have frequented stackoverflow.com for some time now.  Basically I am trying to output serial data from the Arduino to an iPhone.  I installed OpenSSH on the iPhone, and starting minicom from the ssh session.  I have a simple Arduino sketch outputting Hello World.  So I thought I would see Hello World in minicom window but I don't.

My minicom window looks like the following [image]  Yes, the baud rate of the Arduino sketch and minicom are both set to 9600.  If you look in the lower right you will see that minicom states that it is "offline" so I am wondering if this is my problem.

My arduino sketch code looks like the following:

```
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Hello World");
}

void loop()
{
}
```

The solder joints on my iPhone dock connector look good, and I think I breadboarded everything correctly, so I don't understand why I am not seeing Hello World in minicom.

Here is a picture of the dock connector  [image]

Here is a picture of the breadboard [image]

**Update on June 07.**  Well I tried a couple of things and still no luck. I created a [google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Yi9_hcw8XSyYNCG2OJT9oHlTG-dC-Dnuc58VIULa81Q/edit) that I will try and keep updated with my progress, [it can be found here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Yi9_hcw8XSyYNCG2OJT9oHlTG-dC-Dnuc58VIULa81Q/edit).

Comment: Could it be permissions on the /dev/tty?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653692/accessing-to-dev-tty-iap-denied-in-iphone

Comment: Really great question! The offline could be imporantant.. maybe you need to send RTS? also iPhone needs to gointo this Serial Mode somehow does it not- and each version has some newer and more difficult way of doing that. Can you add some references for design? I would love to look into this too.

Comment: OK well i found this.. http://devdot.wikispaces.com/Iphone+Serial+Port+Tutorial  which says you FIRST have to send `*` as a handshaking message and wait for a response(from iphone embedded soft i assume??) and then the Tx/Rx should be ready

Comment: well the handshaking * is news to me.  i wonder if that is necessary if i am only trying to receive serial data.

Comment: well according to this the handshaking isn't necessary, and hasn't been necessary since after FW 1.1
http://modmyi.com/forums/iphone-ipod-touch-sdk-development-discussion/438191-how-do-i-access-serial-uart-usb-connection-iphone.html

Comment: Is your iPhone jail-broken ? I was looking into this some time ago, but I gave up when I got the impression I have to either jail-break my iPhone to talk to the serial connector or pay 60$ for a [Redpark](http://redpark.com) cable. Would be great to see someone do this in an alternate way!

Comment: Speaking of Redpark: It says at http://redpark.com/c2db9_FAQs.html (bit down the page) "Q: How can I tell if my iOS device recognizes the cable? - A: Open the "Settings" app on your iOS device. Select "General", then "About". If the Serial Cable is connected properly, it will appear in the list shown." I wonder if the iPhone also shows anything about your connector there...

Comment: I think [this](http://hcgilje.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/iphone-serial-communication) is what gave me the impression you have to either jail-break your phone or have your serial device certified by Apple.

Comment: My iPhone is running 5.1.1 and is jailbroken using Absinthe jailbreak.

Comment: Also that Arduino sketch code listed above will only print Hello World once to the screen, I found / made a solution with repeatedly print Hello World http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=114900.new;topicseen#new

Comment: I didn't see anything show up in the About section of the Settings on the iPhone :-/

Comment: Well I tried a couple of things and still no luck.
I created a google doc that I will try and keep updated with my progress, it can be found here -> https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Yi9_hcw8XSyYNCG2OJT9oHlTG-dC-Dnuc58VIULa81Q/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got TTL serial receive on the iPhone working yesterday.  Instead of you using `minicom` to check the serial connection I issued the following command: `cat /dev/tty.iap 9600`  This displayed the output my Arduino was sending on the serial TX line.  I also soldered a new dock connector (>.>) I used the pod breakout.

[image]